# access folder and image on page rewriting by htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am little bit confuse about url rewriting...

I have rewritten my contact.php page to contact.html...

```
   RewriteRule ^contact.html/?$ contact.php [NC,L]
```

and it's working fine but when I do it like WordPress

```
   RewriteRule ^contact/contact.html/?$ contact.php [NC,L]
```

it's working but css and image are not called on this page.

I have tried

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

but it's not working.

I want to know if there is any condition in a .htaccess file for handling this as wordpress pages do.

Comment: That depends on how your CSS/JS files are embedded. If they refer to a relative URL, a `/` at the end of that URL will change the URL that the browser calculates.

Answer (score 0):

There are several code works for me. Because you haven't posted actual error in the question. Give it a try..

1} You can try something like this in the `<head>` section of your pages to support relative path for your image/css/js files referenced on that page:

```
<head>
  <base href="http://www.example.com/static-files/" />
</head>
```

reference at http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4

2} link the css files relative to the root directory sample:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/****.css">
```

3} Try this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks but this not working for me ... and i also mention my problem that is error .. the css or image not calling.. or one thing i did not create any folder contact/ its just rewrite by htaccess..

Comment: Yes..You need to point css/js to that rewritten url. Please give me detail which type of error do you get?

Comment: Yes..I understood what you want to say. But you need to give me specific location of css/js to locate error. Otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: Try the fist solution given by me. Define that on your <head> section of contact.php